# I can not play twilio recording's from my site

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to play my recorded calls that I got back from twilio. So far I have a list of all my recorded calls on my site and when I click them it sends me to twilio to listen to them. I then make a ajax request to get back the information from twilio and when I get the information its in byte format. I am not sure how to play that on the browser or how to convert it into a .wav format to listen to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to play the recordings in *WAV* format you can request against the 'recordings api' with a link like this

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.wav?Download=false
```

where `RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is the *RECORDING SID*

Change the .wav to .mp3 and you'll play in *MP3* format.

Also, observe the `Download=false` query string parameter.

Comment: That works when I just want to go to twilio's site to listen to that recording but how would I set that up to where I have a play button on my site and when you click the play button it starts playing the recording without having to redirect me to twilio's site?

Comment: You have the link to the audio resource, you can use it on your page with HTML <audio> Tag.